# hierarki divs center many divs on one row

Tags: html, css

I want to do this, but without the lines between them.

[image]

The problem I have is to center many divs on one row. When i use `float:left` it doesn't work.
Can somebody please help me with the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Put divs of one line to a container div and place it to the center.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
display:inline-block;
```

If you are aiming for IE8+ and etc..

Think this workds for IE6-7

```
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;
zoom:1;
```